# Primefaces slider with float value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I want to use 'InputText Slider with Decimal Value' from [Primefaces.org](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/slider.xhtml) in my JSF2.2 page as shown below:

slider.xhtml

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <p:inputText id="decimal" value="#{sliderView.number2}" />
    <p:slider for="decimal" minValue="0.2" maxValue="7.1" step="0.1" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

And SliderView.java class:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 

@ManagedBean
public class SliderView {

private float number2;

public float getNumber2() {
    return number2;
}

public void setNumber2(float number2) {
    this.number2 = number2;
}
}
```

In this case it throws `javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert [0.2] of type [class java.lang.String] to [int]`.

Even when I change the values of `minValue`, `maxValue` and `step` to managed bean (like `#{sliderView.min}`, `#{sliderView.max}` and `#{sliderView.step}`) it produces Integer result:

slider.xhtml

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        <p:inputText id="decimal" value="#{sliderView.number2}" />
        <p:slider for="decimal" minValue="#{sliderView.min}" maxValue="#
        {sliderView.max}" step="#{sliderView.step}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

SliderView.java class:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 

@ManagedBean
public class SliderView {

private float min = 0.2f;
private float max = 7.1f;
private float step = 0.1f;

private float number2;

public float getMin() {
    return min;
}

public void setMin(float min) {
    this.min = min;
}

public float getMax() {
    return max;
}

public void setMax(float max) {
    this.max = max;
}

public float getStep() {
    return step;
}

public void setStep(float step) {
    this.step = step;
}

public float getNumber2() {
    return number2;
}

public void setNumber2(float number2) {
    this.number2 = number2;
}
}
```

It seems that float or double values are not supported correctly. 
As I understood from [Primefaces Tag Documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/6.0/core/) slider tag supports only Integer values. But why then they gave such strange example of code in the ShowCase?

Comment: In other words, you're not using the same PF version as on PF showcase? Just upgrade then.

Comment: As you pointed the problem was in version. I used 6.0, now updated to 6.1 and everything works perfectly. Thank you very much.